# unterminated string constant QTP VB Script

Tags: sql, excel, vbscript, qtp, vba

I have a VB Script to connect SQL and retrieve value using ADODB recordset. Question: Upon using a multi- line SQL query with JOINs, i received error message : unterminated string constant.Kindly Advise.

Comment: Please show your code. We're not sitting in front of your computer.

Comment: SELECT Distinct c.AccountKey,c.UserId,OnBoardStatus,UserName,FullName,Email,Country,Frequency,Duration,c.LicenseStartDate As SeatStartDate,FirstCoachSessionStartOn,FirstCoachSessionCompletedOn,
GSSCompletionDate,GroupName FROM REPORT.CoachOnboardingStatus c JOIN REPORT.UserDetail ud ON c.userid=ud.userid AND ud.Isactive=1 JOIN REPORT.UserLicense ul ON c.seatid=ul.seatid AND c.Userid = ul.userid
JOIN REPORT.Account acc ON c.AccountKey=acc.AccountKey WHERE c.IsCoachUser = 1 AND c.Accountkey in (SELECT accountkey FROM REPORT.Account WHERE (companyid=4009 AND  grouptype='Seat Group')

Comment: That is an SQL statement. The error message is from your VBScript code. Also, please don't post code in comments as that tends to be unreadable. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your VBScript lacks a closing punctuation mark at the end of a line.  Which means it a syntax error in your script.

Check the syntax of your script, particularly for closing statements